# What are the dependencies for installing vscode 1.32 on ubuntu14.04

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, installation, ubuntu-14.04

I want to install the latest vscode on ubuntu 14.04,
what are the dependencies for that?

I don't have sudo so I have to handle all the dependencies manually.
So I thought maybe someone can share all them so I wont have to find out 1 by 1.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to install Visual Studio Code.

So for the latest stable version, just visit the [official download page](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and choose the architecture ([64bit](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux64_deb) or [32bit](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux32_deb)) you need. By default `Ubuntu 14.04LTS` uses `apt` as package manager, so you'll need the `.deb` file.

Once the download finished, open your download folder (or wherever your downloads are stored). There right click and choose `Open in Terminal`.

Now you can install VSCode by executing the following command (the file name could differ):

```
$ sudo dpkg --install code_1.32.2-1552488294_amd64.deb
```

If there are some unsatisfied dependencies, you will get an error. In this case type in the following:

```
$ sudo apt -f install
```

Then `apt` will automatically install the missing packages and finish the installation of VSCode. It will also add a `.list` file to your `/etc/apt/source.list.d` folder, so that VSCode will always be updated from the official repository when you execute `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.

**Edit:**

The dependencies are:

> libnotify4
>
> libnss3 (>= 2:3.26)
>
> gnupg
>
> apt
>
> libxkbfile1
>
> libsecret-1-0
>
> libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.10.0)
>
> libxss1

Comment: I so sorry, I forgot to mention that I don't have sudo access and I want to install is locally for my user only.

Comment: @IdanEmergi Ah, okay then. I've updated my answer and added every single package VSCode depends on. Good luck  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply download the zip archive version and extract it to destination folder and then run the startup script usually named `code` from its bin folder.

Comment: First thing I did, but it fails with a missing library.

Comment: You mean it didn't run or it didn't extract? And what is the missing library error you are getting?